# 迷う particle meaning

Tags: particles

I don't understand the right use of 迷う, what is the difference between these different options :

- 森で迷う
- 森に迷う
- 道に迷う
- 森で道に迷う

Comment: Does this answer your question? [に迷う vs で迷う, に悩む vs で悩む](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84323/%e3%81%ab%e8%bf%b7%e3%81%86-vs-%e3%81%a7%e8%bf%b7%e3%81%86-%e3%81%ab%e6%82%a9%e3%82%80-vs-%e3%81%a7%e6%82%a9%e3%82%80)

Comment: Not really as I writ in comment for this question, the difference between each one is not cristal clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When 迷う is used with に, what comes before it usually refers to something you are undecided about, such as 判断 (judgement) and 去就 (course of action), not a place. 道 in 道に迷う should be understood as “direction”, or a judgment about which way to go, not a concrete road or street.

When you get lost in a particular place, で should be used. If you get lost in a particular street, you might say 道で迷う just like you say 駅で迷う when you get lost at a station. 森で道に迷う means you get lost in a forest. 森で迷う basically means the same.

で can also be used to limit the scope of things between which you are undecided. ケーキを食べるかどうかで迷ってる and 拒否と受容の間で迷う in this [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84728/43676) can be seen as examples of this usage.

森に迷う is not commonly used in the sense of getting lost in a forest. It has a literary sound to it.